# Getting wrong color when testing LTDC

Tags: stm32

I am testing the LTDC on a dev board. The strange thing is I am getting the wrong color at initialization.

Below is the code for initialzation of LTDC. I get red when I try to fill with blue, and red when I try to fill with blue. There is half word swap happening somwhere but I can't find it

Below is the initialization code:

```
static uint16_t frame_buffer[320 * 240];
 
LTDC_HandleTypeDef hltdc;
 
static uint16_t *ptr_ltdc_draw_buffer;
 
static void ltdc_low_level_init(void);
 
void ltdc_init(void)
{
 /* Low level initialization */
 ltdc_low_level_init();
 
 /* Fill screen with Blue */
 for (int i = 0; i < (320 * 240); i++)
 {
  frame_buffer[i] = 0x001F;
 }
 
 /* */
 hltdc.Instance        = LTDC;
 hltdc.Init.HSPolarity     = LTDC_HSPOLARITY_AL;
 hltdc.Init.VSPolarity     = LTDC_VSPOLARITY_AL;
 hltdc.Init.DEPolarity     = LTDC_DEPOLARITY_AL;
 hltdc.Init.PCPolarity     = LTDC_PCPOLARITY_IIPC;
 hltdc.Init.HorizontalSync   = 3;
 hltdc.Init.VerticalSync    = 3;
 hltdc.Init.AccumulatedHBP   = 46;
 hltdc.Init.AccumulatedVBP   = 15;
 hltdc.Init.AccumulatedActiveW = 366;
 hltdc.Init.AccumulatedActiveH = 255;
 hltdc.Init.TotalWidth     = 374;
 hltdc.Init.TotalHeigh     = 257;
 hltdc.Init.Backcolor.Blue   = 255;
 hltdc.Init.Backcolor.Green  = 0;
 hltdc.Init.Backcolor.Red   = 0;
 
 /* */
 if (HAL_LTDC_Init(&hltdc) != HAL_OK)
 {
  Error_Handler();
 }
 
 LTDC_LayerCfgTypeDef pLayerCfg = {0};
 
 /* */
 pLayerCfg.WindowX0      = 0;
 pLayerCfg.WindowX1      = 320;
 pLayerCfg.WindowY0      = 0;
 pLayerCfg.WindowY1      = 240;
 pLayerCfg.PixelFormat     = LTDC_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB565;
 pLayerCfg.Alpha        = 255;
 pLayerCfg.Alpha0       = 225;
 pLayerCfg.BlendingFactor1   = LTDC_BLENDING_FACTOR1_CA;
 pLayerCfg.BlendingFactor2   = LTDC_BLENDING_FACTOR2_CA;
 pLayerCfg.FBStartAdress    = (uint32_t) ptr_ltdc_draw_buffer;
 pLayerCfg.ImageWidth     = 320;
 pLayerCfg.ImageHeight     = 240;
 pLayerCfg.Backcolor.Blue   = 255;
 pLayerCfg.Backcolor.Green   = 0;
 pLayerCfg.Backcolor.Red    = 0;
 
 /* */
 if (HAL_LTDC_ConfigLayer(&hltdc, &pLayerCfg, 0) != HAL_OK)
 {
  Error_Handler();
 }
}
 
/**
 * @brief Private function template.
 * @note  Note 1.
 * @param pram1 description of param1.
 * @param pram2 description of param1.
 * @retval Return description
 */
static void ltdc_low_level_init(void)
{
 GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
 RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};
 
 /*
  * Initializes the peripherals clock
  */
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_LTDC;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3M = 6;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3N = 129;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3P = 2;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3Q = 2;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3R = 53;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3RGE = RCC_PLL3VCIRANGE_1;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3VCOSEL = RCC_PLL3VCOWIDE;
 PeriphClkInitStruct.PLL3.PLL3FRACN = 0;
 if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
 {
  Error_Handler();
 }
 
 /* LTDC clock enable */
 __HAL_RCC_LTDC_CLK_ENABLE();
 
 /* GPIO clock enable */
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
 
 /*
 LTDC GPIO Configuration :
 PA1   ------> LTDC_R2
 PB0   ------> LTDC_R3
 PA11  ------> LTDC_R4
 PA9   ------> LTDC_R5
 PB1   ------> LTDC_R6
 PE15  ------> LTDC_R7
 
 PD6   ------> LTDC_B2
 PA8   ------> LTDC_B3
 PE12  ------> LTDC_B4
 PA3   ------> LTDC_B5
 PB8   ------> LTDC_B6
 PB9   ------> LTDC_B7
 
 PA6   ------> LTDC_G2
 PE11  ------> LTDC_G3
 PB10  ------> LTDC_G4
 PB11  ------> LTDC_G5
 PC7   ------> LTDC_G6
 PD3   ------> LTDC_G7
 
 PA4   ------> LTDC_VSYNC
 PE13   ------> LTDC_DE
 PE14   ------> LTDC_CLK
 PC6   ------> LTDC_HSYNC
 */
 
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_6
            |GPIO_PIN_9|USB_DFU_DM___LTDC_R4_Pin;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_LTDC;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14
            |GPIO_PIN_15;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF13_LTDC;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
 
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_6;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
 GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF14_LTDC;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
```

Comment: What is this "LTDC"?

Comment: @Uwe the OP seems to have a 16-bit display as they're using the `LTDC_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB565` configuration.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica "LTDC" is the "LCD-TFT Display Controller" module in some STM32 devices.

Comment: If blue is 5 bit then hltdc.Init.Backcolor.Blue   = 255; is wrong it should be = 31;

Comment: I don't know your display, but some display models interpret 16 bit colors with blue and red exchanged. Either you can configure this in the display or you just have to live with it. The comment area "LTDC GPIO Configuration" shows an 18 bit parallel interface, do you use this?

Comment: @Uwe the LTDC internally uses 32-bit color (for alpha-blending of layers, etc.) so you give it 8-bit values for those registers, but it has pixel-format converters which allow you to use a different 'input' format for the frame-buffer and 'output' format for the display. It performs the pixel format conversion on-the-fly as it reads from the framebuffer and outputs to the display.